# Issue while updating the value of a key in the firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a multiple choice question app.I want to update the score the user have scored after fetching the previous scores and adding the new score to the database.

I have tried to update the score with the help of-

static variable:It resets the previously existed data and overwrites the new data on it.

local variable:The value gets updated in the anonymous class but it reverses back when the variable comes out of anonymous class.

```
public int total=1,correct=0,inCorrect=0;
public static int data=0;  
if(total>5)
        {

            updateScore();

            Log.i("Function","the updated value of data "+data);

            Intent intent=new 
 Intent(QuizGeneral.this,ResultActivity.class);
            String a= String.valueOf((correct));
            intent.putExtra("correct",a );
            a= String.valueOf((inCorrect));
            intent.putExtra("incorrect",a);
            startActivity(intent);}

private void updateScore(){

    Log.i("Function","We are int the function now");
    FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Log.i("Function","We have got thr reference of the user");

    String Uid=user.getUid();
    Log.i("Function","Received the Uid"+Uid);

    FirebaseDatabase db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Log.i("Function","received the instance");

    final DatabaseReference 
reference=db.getReference("Users/"+Uid+"/maths/");

    Log.i("Function","we have got the reference");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.i("Function","We are in anonymous function 
 now"+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

            Object str = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.i("Function","We are getting the function now");

            data= Integer.valueOf(str.toString());
            //data2[0] = Integer.valueOf(str.toString());

            Log.i("Function","the value is"+data);


            Log.i("Function","correct value is"+correct);

            Log.i("Function","the new value is"+data);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
   // Log.i("Function","the value of data beffore setting to db is"+data);

        int x=data+correct;
        Log.i("Function","The correct value is"+x);
        reference.setValue(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

put this `

```
    int x=data+correct;
    Log.i("Function","The correct value is"+x);
    reference.setValue(x);`
```

inside the **onDataChange()** function code. You will get the correct Results.

This is happening because the code above runs before the value of data and correct are changed, so if you out this code inside the onDataChange function you will get correct result as after updating the value your data is put to firebase.

Comment: When I am using these in onDataChange() function the value goes on increasing and increasing it won't stop.now 
**2019-08-26 21:34:52.256 31154-31154/? I/Function: the value is109911
2019-08-26 21:34:52.256 31154-31154/? I/Function: correct value is1
2019-08-26 21:34:52.256 31154-31154/? I/Function: the new value is109911
2019-08-26 21:34:52.256 31154-31154/? I/Function: The correct value is109912
2019-08-26 21:34:52.257 31154-31154/? I/Function: We are in anonymous function now109912**

Comment: Kindly suggest any other solution.....This might be happening because this anonymous function**reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)**  gets activated every time the data is  changed as we are changing the data in the function itself so it will get incremented everytime and this loop will go on forever.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

There are 2 methods:

-addValueEventListener()-works for every time the data changes or get triggered everytime the data changes

-addListenerForSingleValueEvent()-works only for a single time when the data changes.